# $lookup Equality Match is working but $lookup in Pipeline and with Condition is not working

Tags: mongodb, lookup, aggregation

I have two collections 1. Address and 2. userInfo, I am tring to find the addresses which belongs to a user with the help of aggregation pipeline. It's working fine when I am doing simple $lookup but return empty array of address when I use $pipeline in $lookup.

```
db.userInfo.insertMany(
[
    {
        "contact_name": "rommel",
        "age": 37,
        "sex" : "male",
        "citizenship" : "Filipino"
    },
    {
        "contact_name": "gary",
        "age": 32,
        "sex" : "male",
        "citizenship" : "Filipino"
    }
]
```

);

```
db.address.insertMany(
    [
        {
            "name": "rommel",
            "blk_no": 12,
            "street" : "dewey street",
            "city" : "olongapo",
            "userId" : ObjectId("<user-id">)
        },
        {
            "name": "gary",
            "blk_no": 15,
            "street" : "gordon street",
            "city" : "olongapo"
             "userId" : ObjectId("<user-id">)
        }
    ]
);
```

The query below returns desired result

```
    db.userInfo.aggregate([
    { $lookup:
        {
           from: "address",
           localField: "_id",
           foreignField: "userId",
           as: "address"
        }
    }
]).pretty();
```

result:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("60194460ab69d4694e6152aa"),
        "contact_name" : "rommel",
        "age" : 37,
        "sex" : "male",
        "citizenship" : "Filipino",
        "address" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("601944b8ab69d4694e6152ac"),
                        "name" : "rommel",
                        "blk_no" : 12,
                        "street" : "dewey street",
                        "city" : "olongapo",
                        "userId" : ObjectId("60194460ab69d4694e6152aa")
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("60194460ab69d4694e6152ab"),
        "contact_name" : "gary",
        "age" : 32,
        "sex" : "male",
        "citizenship" : "Filipino",
        "address" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("601944b8ab69d4694e6152ad"),
                        "name" : "gary",
                        "blk_no" : 15,
                        "street" : "gordon street",
                        "city" : "olongapo",
                        "userId" : ObjectId("60194460ab69d4694e6152ab")
                }
        ]
}
```

but this query does not return desried result

```
    db.userInfo.aggregate([
 { $lookup:
     {
       from: "address",
       let: { userId: "$userId" },
       pipeline: [
            { $match:
                { $expr:
                    { $eq: ["$_id", "$$userId" ] }
                }
            }
        ],
        as: "address"
        }
 }
]).pretty();
```

result:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("60194460ab69d4694e6152aa"),
        "contact_name" : "rommel",
        "age" : 37,
        "sex" : "male",
        "citizenship" : "Filipino",
        "address" : [ ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("60194460ab69d4694e6152ab"),
        "contact_name" : "gary",
        "age" : 32,
        "sex" : "male",
        "citizenship" : "Filipino",
        "address" : [ ]
}
```

Comment: you are passing wrong field in `let`, try `let: { userId: "$_id" }` _id that is your local field, second change your foreignfield in $match stage `{ $eq: ["$userId", "$$userId" ] }`

Comment: @turivishal Working fine :-)